# OleDbException was unhandled - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, sql, database

Im getting error

> OleDbException was unhandled - Data type mismatch in criteria
>   expression

on the OleDbDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader() line can anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace posSystem
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=userName.accdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From userAndPAss Where ID = '" + txtBoxUserName + "' and Password = '" + txtBoxPassword + "';", conn);
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader re = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(re.Read()
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Login Successfull"); 



            }
            else{
            MessageBox.Show("Login NOT Successfull, Try again!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always use parameters to avoid sql injection:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * From userAndPAss Where ID = @id and Password = @password", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtBoxUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtBoxPassword.Text);
```

You need to specify the Text property of the TextBox, not the TextBox control itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know much about connecting to Access, but here are some typical issues you might want to check:

- check the datatypes of your table-columns - is "ID" really a string?
- check if columnnames are reserved keywords in access (especially "Password")
- access may have some problems, if the cell-value is null (use "Nz")